# How could I reuse my code behind?

Tags: wpf, xaml, code-behind

I have two controls with quite different layout, but their XAML structure is quite similar (same kind of containers and even same element names), so that *their code behind is identical*. Unfortunately, so far, I had to repeat the code for all event handlers on each of the two classes.

I am now in the process of extracting common functionality to satellite classes, using composition, but still the redundancy of constructors, field declarations, and initialization bothers me a lot.

So the question boils down to:

> Is there a way to avoid redundant code behind code when two UserControls have only layout differences, but identical code-behind?

Comment: IF they share the same events and logic, why don't you create a view model that implements commands?. In this case both controls will use the same view model and you don't need to rewrite the events again. It is better to keep the code  behind empty actually for better results. Look at this for how to do them, http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/commands/using-commands/

Comment: Depending on what you are doing attached properties may be right. They compose nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF seperates those concerns using a controltemplate that can be changed. The "code-behind" is the behavior. You do not need a ViewModel for that.

Comment: I think you nailed it. In fact, as I have explicitly stated, only the layout / coloring / presentation changes from one to the other. That is the exact use case for control templates: having different XAML for the same class. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are few solutions:

1. Create abstract class inherited from UserControl. Place the common logic in the BaseClass.

   Than change your "UserControl" to inherit from your BaseClass instead of UserControl. So at the end you will have two UserControls inherided from your baseclass.
2. Consider creating Control, instead of UserControl. You can create two ControlTemplates for the control.

   ```
   <local:YourControl Template="{StaticResource Template1}" />
   <local:YourControl Template="{StaticResource Template2}" />
   ```
3. In MVVM, you can easily create multiple views for single viewmodel. While some people preffers to single view per viewmodel and vice versa, you can create two viewmodels inherided from one common base, or SecondViewModel inherited from FirstViewModel.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I ended up going with the Template approach (it's actually the obvious way to go, now that it has been figured out).

Answer (score 0):

What is your requirement actually is known only to you. I am going by the question which you have emphasized :

```
Is there a way to avoid redundant code behind code when two UserControls 
have only layout differences, but identical code-behind?
```

If you want flexibility in separating views for different layouts, then best is to go for loose XAML files. And load these files at runtime. You can change these files at runtime without making changes to your application code. Just like we can make changes to CSS/JS files on the fly.

I have developed an application catering to your needs. I have developed 3 usercontrols:

1. UserControl1 : Using loose text file for layout
2. UserControl2 : Using common viewmodel where you wire up your event handlers centrally. But this might not fit here.
3. UserControl3 : Using loose xaml file for layout

You can check, and if some improvement needs to be done, I will do it.

[Dropbox link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zz2dqvjaortkvee/WpfResources.rar?dl=0)

Comment: This is the easiest approach and will work with least/no effort at all.

Comment: Just for information, I didn't downvoted, and thank you for your answer. What you mean by "loose XAML" would be ControlTemplates? See the accepted answer.

Answer (score -1):

The best practice based on the limited scope will be to use the MVVM pattern and move the code to its appropriate place.

But to answer your question, specifically, I would factor out code into one or more Portable Class Libraries. Depending on the complexity of the app, you could just factor out the code into classes within the Project.

Comment: Thanks for the down vote. I'll still answer your obvious question of how you use your code behind, you would reuse it in my first example in the ViewModel and possible View. And in the second example, in would be reused in the Portable Class Library. Tool.

Comment: Just for your information, it wasn't me who downvoted, and thanks for your answer!